# Manually synchronizing two BTRFS snapshots with RSYNC

Tags: rsync, backup, btrfs

#### Question

Is there a way to synchronize two BTRFS snapshots manually on different disks and mark them as identical (set the parent/child relationship) reliably?

#### Problem

I was synchronizing my snapshots with my external disk. Naturally, I'm taking advantage of `btrfs send -p $PARENT $CURRENT` which greatly reduces the amount of data needed to be sent over the wire. To be able to send the snapshot by only using the diff, the `PARENT` snapshot must exist on both disks.

I mistakenly deleted all of my old snapshots on my laptop so all common snapshots are gone. Since there is no common point, I have to send entire snapshot for the first time, which is about 800GB. `rsync` says there are only 100MB of difference between my oldest snapshot on my laptop and the newest snapshot on the external disk. That's why I don't want to send whole 800GB again instead of sending 100MB.

#### Idea

I thought I could

- create a rw snapshot of oldest snapshot on the external disk (name this `foo`),
- use `rsync` to synchronize `foo` with the source snapshot on the laptop,
- then create a readonly snapshot of `foo` on external disk (`foo-readonly`),
- somehow mark `foo-readonly`'s `Received UUID` with `UUID` of the source snapshot.

But, since rsync won't synchronize *all files* (block device files and such), would it break anything in the future if I would keep incremental snapshot technique for the rest of the transfers?

Or ignoring the possible missing files, is there any reliable way to synchronize two snapshots with `rsync` for this sort of scenario?

Comment: Try `bscp` https://vog.github.io/bscp/

Comment: Rsync can synchronize block devices via `--devices` parameter.

Comment: I discourage using block device synchronization tools, such as those mentioned above, because your source and destination BTRFS filesystems are indeed separate filesystems; even if they share content. If you were to synchronize the filesystems at the block device level, assuming that would work, BTRFS will think both devices are part of the same filesystem. That would be disastrous. See https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gotchas#Block-level_copies_of_devices

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Your point is accurate. But this block level synchronization will be performed only for the first time. If it works, I think changing UUID of target would resolve the gotcha of the mentioned method. Thanks for reminding.